# How to filter the products by selecting multiple attribute values in same attribute from layered navigation by adding multi-select feature Magento2

Tags: magento2

In default Magento, we can't filter the products by selecting multiple attribute values in same attribute.
For example,

Attribute name: **Price**

we can filter the products by selecting one of the attribute value from **price** attribute.

[image]
After selecting that attribute value, the **price** attribute hidden from layered navigation attribute list.
[image]

How to overcome it from default Magento?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to overcome from default Magento.

We can add checkbox for each attribute value in **filter.phtml** template file for mullti-select and get selected attribute code and value.

Then we can send the same attribute values as array to `Vendor/Magento/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php` class and filter the products based on same attribute values.

Override `Vendor/Magento/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter.phtml` to add checkbox for each attribute value to select multiple attributes.

**Step 1:** To override **filter.phtml** file, create a layout file and add reference block in `Vendor/Magento/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` as below

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.navigation.renderer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::layer/filter.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2:** Add checkbox in **filter.phtml**

```
<ol class="items">
    <?php foreach ($filterItems as $filterItem): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() > 0): ?>
                <form class="checkbox-form" id="checkbox-form-<?= $filterItem->getFilter()->getRequestVar() . '-' . $filterItem->getValueString() ?>">
                    <?php $filter = $filterItem->getFilter()->getData();
                    $attribute = ''; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($filter['attribute_model'])): ?>
                    <?php $attribute = $filter['attribute_model']['allow_multiSelect']; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($attribute): ?>
                    <input class="checkbox-value" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-value"
                           id="<?= $filterItem->getFilter()->getRequestVar() . '-' .
                           $filterItem->getValueString() ?>"
                           value="<?= $filterItem->getFilter()->getRequestVar() . '=' .
                           $filterItem->getValueString() ?>"/>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($filterItem->getUrl()) ?>"
                       class="filter-item filter-item-<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(uniqid('', true)) ?>"
                        <span>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */
                            $filterItem->getLabel() ?><?php
                            if ($viewModel->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?><span
                                class="count"><?= /* @noEscape */
                            (int)$filterItem->getCount() ?><span
                                    class="filter-count-label"><?php
                                if ($filterItem->getCount() === 1): ?>
                                    <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('item')) ?><?php
                                else:
                                    ?><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('items')) ?><?php
                                endif; ?></span></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </form>
            <?php else: ?>
                <form>
                    <span class="check-box">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle"
                               onclick='window.location.href("<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($filterItem->getUrl()) ?>")'/>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */
                        $filterItem->getLabel() ?><?php
                        if ($viewModel->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?><span
                            class="count"><?= /* @noEscape */
                        (int)$filterItem->getCount() ?><span
                                class="filter-count-label"><?php
                            if ($filterItem->getCount() === 1): ?>
                                <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('item')) ?><?php
                            else:
                                ?><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('items')) ?><?php
                            endif; ?></span></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

Now we can look the checkbox in attribute and able to select multiple attribute value.

[image]

**Step 3:** Get each selected attribute code and value and passed that values as array to **Apply** method in `Vendor/Magento/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php` class

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Magento\Model\Layer\Filter;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filter\StripTags;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Attribute extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filter\StripTags
     */
    private $tagFilter;

    public function __construct(
        ItemFactory           $filterItemFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Layer                 $layer,
        DataBuilder           $itemDataBuilder,
        StripTags             $tagFilter,
        array                 $data = []
    ) {
        $this->tagFilter = $tagFilter;
        parent::__construct($filterItemFactory, $storeManager, $layer, $itemDataBuilder, $tagFilter, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Apply attribute option filter to product collection
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return $this
     */
    public function apply(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $attributeValue = [];
        $attributeOption = $request->getParam($this->_requestVar);
        if (!is_null($attributeOption) && strpos($attributeOption, ',')) {
            $attributeValue = explode(',', $attributeOption);
        }
       
        if (empty($attributeOption) && !is_numeric($attributeOption)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $attribute = $this->getAttributeModel();
        /** @var Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()
            ->getProductCollection();
        foreach ($attributeValue as $value) {
            $productCollection->addFieldToFilter(
                $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                $this->convertAttributeValue($attribute, $value)
            );
        }
        foreach ($attributeValue as $value) {
            $label = $this->getOptionText($value);
            $this->getLayer()
                ->getState()
                ->addFilter($this->_createItem($label, $value));
        }
        $this->setItems([]); // set items to disable show filtering

        return $this;
    }
```

Here the same attribute values are passed as array and in **Apply** method, each attribute values products are collected and return.

[image]